# Which model to use for sales forecasting in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, time-series, forecasting

I want to predict the sales (sold_qty) of a store considering all the variables listed below. The dataset contains following variables -

1. `Date` - ranges from 2012-11-22 to 2016-05-26
2. `sold_qty` - number of items sold on that day
3. `trans` - number of transactions takes place on that day
4. `calander_day_of_year` - day number of that year
5. `weekday_name` - name of that day
6. `month name` - name of the month of that day
7. `Temp` - temperature of that day
8. `Precip` - amount of rainfall/snowfall on that day
9. `Climate_events` - weather conditions on that day like(fog,rain,snow)
10. `weekend` - whether the day is a weekend or not?
11. `Holiday_flg` - whether the day has a holiday?

Also, on exploratory data analysis, I found that temperature is only affecting sales when temp is below -3 degree Celsius.

Please suggest a model to do the forecast.